# how does one click an unclickable submit button in wdio?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, wdio

I have website that has a login form. I can enter in the user and password, however, when I try to click the submit button. Nothing happens.

My setup is for nodejs with wdio...

package.json

```
{
  "name": "wido",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.11.2",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.11.2",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.11.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.11.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "chromedriver": "^114.0.2",
    "wdio-allure-reporter": "^0.8.3",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1",
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^8.11.2"
  }
}
```

the table

```
<div class="loginMainDiv">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-top: 80px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><span id="Label2">Benutzername</span></td>
    <td class="pl10"><input name="UserName" type="text" id="UserName" tabindex="1" class="text" onfocus="this.select();"></td>
    <td><span id="UserNameRequired" style="visibility:hidden;">*</span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:10px"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td><span id="Label3">Kennwort</span></td>
    <td class="pl10 right"><input name="Password" type="password" id="Password" class="text" onfocus="this.select();"></td>
    <td><span id="PasswordRequired" style="visibility:hidden;">*</span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:10px"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
<tr>
    ***<td class="pl10 right" colspan="2"><input id="LoginButton" class="textbutton_default" type="submit" name="LoginButton" value="Anmelden"></td>
    <td>***</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:20px"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-top:30px;" colspan="2" align="right"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

the sample test is as follows...

wdio.conf.js

```
  it('Should set user', async () => {
    browser.waitUntil(
      () => browser.execute(() => document.readyState === 'complete'),
      {
        timeout: 60 * 1000, // 60 seconds
        timeoutMsg: 'page load failure'
      }
    );
    const input = await $('#UserName');
    await input.clearValue()
    await input.addValue('user')
    browser.saveScreenshot('images/nom-connexion.png');
    console.log(await input.getValue()); // outputs: 'user'
  });

  it('Should set pass', async () => {
    const input = await $('#Password');
    await input.clearValue()
    await input.addValue('pass')
    browser.saveScreenshot('images/motdepass-connexion.png');
    console.log(await input.getValue()); // outputs: 'pass'
});

  // it("Feed in details and initiate login", () => {
     // $("//input[@id='UserName']").setValue("user");
    // $("//input[@id='Password']").setValue("pass");
    // $("//input[@id='LoginButton']").click();
  //   browser.saveScreenshot('images/changer-connexion.png'); 
  // });

  it('Should submit', async () => {
    // const submitbutton = await $('#LoginButton');
    // await submitbutton.click(); 
    // browser.submitForm('#LoginButton');
    // browser.elementClick('#LoginButton')
    // await browser.setTimeout({ 'pageLoad': 10000 })
    // $('#LoginButton').click();
    // $('#LoginButton').submit();
    browser.click('#LoginButton');
  });

  it("get portal Title", () => {
    const pagetitle = browser.getTitle()
    console.log('Title of the webpage is -' + pagetitle)
    browser.saveScreenshot('images/pendant-connexion.png'); 
  });
```

I tried several options from google and nothing worked.

A. - feedin the object directly to the browser

```
  it('Should submit', async () => {
    browser.click('#LoginButton');
  });
```

and I get an error..

```
[chrome 114.0.5735.133 linux #0-0] browser.click is not a function
```

B. Using submit

```
  it('Should submit', async () => {
    $('#LoginButton').submit();
  });
```

and it does nothing... In the log it says it was clicked, but I take a picture after login and I have just the login form. ?

[image: pendant-connexion.png]

C. - using click

```
  it('Should submit', async () => {
    $('#LoginButton').click();
  });
```

and it does nothing... In the log it says it was clicked, but I take a picture after login and I have just the login form. Same as option b.

log file

```
2023-07-28T17:58:42.149Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementSendKeys("70C2B84D299CC45CE61C93A79B087FDA_element_5", "<Screenshot[base64]>")
2023-07-28T17:58:42.150Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:9515/session/5daf3b8cc89deba3c116fb61f4dffafe/element/70C2B84D299CC45CE61C93A79B087FDA_element_5/value
2023-07-28T17:58:42.150Z INFO webdriver: DATA { text: 'user' }
2023-07-28T17:58:42.183Z INFO webdriver: RESULT null
2023-07-28T17:58:42.184Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND getElementProperty("70C2B84D299CC45CE61C93A79B087FDA_element_5", "value")
2023-07-28T17:58:42.184Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://localhost:9515/session/5daf3b8cc89deba3c116fb61f4dffafe/element/70C2B84D299CC45CE61C93A79B087FDA_element_5/property/value
2023-07-28T17:58:42.185Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND takeScreenshot()
2023-07-28T17:58:42.185Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://localhost:9515/session/5daf3b8cc89deba3c116fb61f4dffafe/screenshot
2023-07-28T17:58:42.191Z INFO webdriver: RESULT user
2023-07-28T17:58:42.192Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("css selector", "#Password")
2023-07-28T17:58:42.192Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:9515/session/5daf3b8cc89deba3c116fb61f4dffafe/element
2023-07-28T17:58:42.192Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'css selector', value: '#Password' }
2023-07-28T17:58:42.415Z INFO webdriver: RESULT iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAWgCAYAAAC/kV7ZAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6...
2023-07-28T17:58:42.429Z INFO webdriver: RESULT {
  'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '70C2B84D299CC45CE61C93A79B087FDA_element_7'
}
2023-07-28T17:58:42.433Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClear("70C2B84D299CC45CE61C93A79B087FDA_element_7")
2023-07-28T17:58:42.433Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:9515/session/5daf3b8cc89deba3c116fb61f4dffafe/element/70C2B84D299CC45CE61C93A79B087FDA_element_7/clear
2023-07-28T17:58:42.470Z INFO webdriver: RESULT null
2023-07-28T17:58:42.471Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementSendKeys("70C2B84D299CC45CE61C93A79B087FDA_element_7", "<Screenshot[base64]>")
2023-07-28T17:58:42.471Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:9515/session/5daf3b8cc89deba3c116fb61f4dffafe/element/70C2B84D299CC45CE61C93A79B087FDA_element_7/value
2023-07-28T17:58:42.471Z INFO webdriver: DATA { text: 'pass' }
2023-07-28T17:58:42.572Z INFO webdriver: RESULT null
2023-07-28T17:58:42.573Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND getElementProperty("70C2B84D299CC45CE61C93A79B087FDA_element_7", "value")
2023-07-28T17:58:42.577Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://localhost:9515/session/5daf3b8cc89deba3c116fb61f4dffafe/element/70C2B84D299CC45CE61C93A79B087FDA_element_7/property/value
2023-07-28T17:58:42.583Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND takeScreenshot()
2023-07-28T17:58:42.583Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://localhost:9515/session/5daf3b8cc89deba3c116fb61f4dffafe/screenshot
2023-07-28T17:58:42.596Z INFO webdriver: RESULT pass
2023-07-28T17:58:42.597Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("css selector", "#LoginButton")
2023-07-28T17:58:42.598Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:9515/session/5daf3b8cc89deba3c116fb61f4dffafe/element
2023-07-28T17:58:42.598Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'css selector', value: '#LoginButton' }
2023-07-28T17:58:42.600Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND getTitle()
2023-07-28T17:58:42.614Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND takeScreenshot()
2023-07-28T17:58:42.615Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://localhost:9515/session/5daf3b8cc89deba3c116fb61f4dffafe/screenshot
```

Anyone have any ideas why I have an unclickable link?

Comment: Not part of your question but I wanted to tell you how happy I am to see that you are writing front end tests using the DOM. Too many developers write unit tests for components by pretending they are services. They would have used a normal button with an onclick event handler method, then written unit tests to test that method directly and there are whole dimensions of things that can go wrong and untested that way. *You* are testing the UI via actually manipulating the UI. 

Answer (score 0):

It's not an angular thing, it's an HTML thing. Submit buttons must be within a [`FORM` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) that specifies what should be done on submit.